# Analysis problem covering rationality/irrationality

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f_1$ be the function defined on $[a,b]$ by setting $f_1(x)=0$ if $x$ is rational, and $f_1(x)=1$ if $x$ is irrational. Show that every lower sum of $f$ on $[0,1]$ is $≤0$. Concluding that$$\underline\int^1_0 f(x)dx=0$$ i.e.

NOTE$*$ (I already proved that every closed interval [a,b] is a subset of R contains at least one irrational number and that every closed interval [a,b] is a subset of R contains at least one rational number. 
I have an idea of using $[0,1] \supseteq I_1 \supseteq I_2 \supseteq \dotsc$
but I see nothing else, can I get any leading ideas or a set structure on how to deal with this particular problem.)

Comment: The function you gave is not Riemann integrable, for the upper and lower sums would have to be close for thin enough partitions. Even if you use Lebesgue integral, that would give $\int_[0,1]f_1=1$, for the rationals have measure zero.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot prove an incorrect statement.

The integral does not exist in Riemannian Sense. However, what you can show is: $$\underline\int^1_0 f(x)dx=0$$ i.e.
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}m_i\Delta x_i=0$$
This is easy, since no matter how small partition you choose, there exists a rational number in it. So, $m_i=0$.